# Different CSS Stylesheet versions for different body parts

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, stylesheet

I am developing a one page website. I need a bootstrap "modal" class popup to show up when I click on a button. However the template I am using is done in Bootstrap Version 1. I need the "modal" popup to be in Bootstrap v3. Is there any way that I can make this specific part of the html body to use Bootstrap v3?

If I try to include the link reference to Bootstrap v3 at the top of the page the template gets messed up and unclean.
Please help....

Answer (score 0):

**Best solution, but not cross-browser**

This is not supported by all browsers but you can use :

```
<style scoped>
@import url("bootstrap-3.css");
</style>
```

Put this in the modal container `<div>`.

**Cross browser solution**

Copy over the modal component from bootstrap 3 then remove the bootstrap 1 modal component (in the css).

**Other cross browser solution**

Rebuild your template on top of bootstrap-3.

Comment: I tried the first solution:  
However there is an error for the import statement that says: 
Unexpected token IMPORT_SYM found.

Also if I include that right inside my modal <div> still the page fonts and layout- all changes

Comment: Are you using Firefox ? Chrome requires a special flag enabled.

Comment: I am developing using NetBeans and Running on Chrome.
Can you please explain in a bit detail..

Comment: The scoped attribute of <style> is only supported in Firefox. It works on chrome if you enable an experimental flag in chrome://flags

Comment: So if the scoped attribute is not recognized, the bootstrap-3 css will affect the whole page instead of just the modal.

Comment: Browser support for <style scoped> : http://caniuse.com/style-scoped
Documentation for <style scoped> : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style#A_scoped_stylesheet